# Не навешивается скрипт JQ при добавлении блоков с сервера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Не понимаю почему так происходит, но есть такая задачка. У меня подгружаются посты из отдельного файла(то есть там цикл), получается с сервера все грузится и добавляется в нужное место. На первый пост навешивается скрипт нормально, на второй уже частично. То есть `e.preventDefault();` отрабатывает, ссылки не переходят по якорю. А вот функция при клике уже на втором элементе не отрабатывает. Не могу понять почему так.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#vacancy-click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('#vacancy-wrapp').find($('#modal-vacancy')).arcticmodal();
})
```

Получается на ссылку навешивает событие, а вот клик полностью отработает только на первом посте.

Comment: `.find($('#modal-vacancy'))` ---> `.find('#modal-vacancy')` ?

Comment: аа.. ну если везде навешены идентификаторы, а не классы - то всё понятно

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Да, нужно быть внимательнее)